# Using socket.io with sails js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

While there used to be very good documentation for using sockets, thanks to [Irl Nathon's Sails Cast series](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/10/10/building-a-sails-application-ep21-integrating-socket-dot-io-and-sails-with-custom-controller-actions-using-real-time-model-events/). Things have changed in **v0.11**, with the sails team wrapping and burying the socket.io routines.

The sails site *e.g. [SailsSocket](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/sails-socket)* is maddeningly concise, saying what to do, but not how or where to do it, or if I need to **npm** or **bower** something.  This has been particularly frustrating trying to  use the `sails.config.sockets` talked about on the sails site.  Which I cannot even find in my v0.11 directories.

First, I would like to know how and where to create my own response to a `io.socket.get` or `.post` or whatever.  Right now when I do a get with something like:

```
`io.socket.request({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/sites/2',
  params: {},
  headers: {}
},function serverResponded(body, JWR){console.log("Body: ", JSON.stringify(body,null, 4)); console.log(' JWR: ', JWR.body)});'
```

I get back:

```
undefined
VM1149:7 "Not implemented in core yet"
VM1149:7  JWR:  Not implemented in core yet
```

I can see the sites being called in the sails console, but nothing comes across.

I believe it is because I have defined my own routes and have my own find: function in my site controller and I manually need to push something into the server side socket.  But I am confused as to how I am to call a whole page with HTTP and just the tables with socket.io in the same controller routine.

- Where do I write my own low level **socket.io** routines that can be called from a web page?
- Do I still do it in the `app.js` file?

Sails Cast showed it being done there, but again things have changed.

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021125/sails-io-js-io-socket-get-user-not-implemented-in-core-yet/40027253#40027253) thread help you? I think that the question is quite similar...

Comment: please provide more info how are you configuring your sail hooks

Answer (score 1):

Sails "virtual requests" (what they call these socket.io-based HTTP-ish request) are generally used to retrieve or post JSON data to the server. Additionally, if a client-side script makes a virtual request, the server may add or remove the requesting socket to/from rooms.

Note that using a "virtual method" will ultimately run the same controller action, but will set `req.isSocket = true`.

This example is a view that renders a view for HTML-wanting requests but returns JSON data for socket-based requests:

```
...
// 'get /sites/:id': 'SomeController.showSite' (should be put in your `routes.js`)
showSite: function(req, res) {
  // load something from the database
  Site.findOne(req.param('id')).exec(function(err, site) {
    // handler errors (same for HTTP or sockets)
    if (err) return res.serverError();
    if (!site) return res.notFound();

    if (req.isSocket) return res.json(site); // render JSON response for our `site` object
    else return res.view('sites/show', {site: site}); // render an HTML view
  });
}
```

As for low-level `socket.io`, sails provides the global variable `io` (from sails.io.js), which is an instance of `SailsSocket`. It allows you to make HTTP-ish "virtual requests". More info [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client) (although it seems you have already read all there is to read about SailsSocket :). You can access the underlying `socket.io` client with `io.socket._raw`.

```
// do this in the browser. 
// sails.io.js should be included in layout.ejs by default.
io.socket.get('/site/2', console.log); // "virtual request"
// neat little trick     ^^^^^^^^^^^     for testing :)
var rawIO = io.socket._raw;
rawIO.emit('some:event', "using native socket.io");
```

Hope this helps!