# sailsjs sockets with multiple nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, sails.js

I have a SailsJS web application hosted on AWS across multiple EC2 instances. We want to add websocket integration for our use case but problem is that with multiple nodes, we need to be able to access the websocket from different nodes. How may we achieve this? I have read up on the following to no avail:

[node-websocket-server: possible to have multiple, separate "broadcasts" for a single node.js process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445883/node-websocket-server-possible-to-have-multiple-separate-broadcasts-for-a-si)

[Connect to Sails WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043627/connect-to-sails-websocket)

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/849

Any help is appreciated!